# Is it possible to get node data from a different object, than the one being rendered?

Tags: node-editor, objects, shaders, linked-data

More specifically, if I have a curve that a specific object is following, and I want rendering to change based on a property of how far along this track that specific object is, can I pull the exact coordinates of the curve into the shader editor, for the constrained object?

That sounded a little clearer in my head. Here's an illustration.[image]

Currently, I can simply copy-paste the location of the curve into my nodes, and do my shader math on the basis of that; but it feels extraordinarily inelegant. I can kind of understand this on the basis of limited data to the GPU, but I'm rendering on a CPU here. What can I do to get something like the illustrated node at the bottom left, so future adjustments of the curve don't also require me to alter my shader?